# i have a question, how i can use a reference field from firestore

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

[image: firestore myProblemRef]

I'm using React and Firestore

```
export const getBills = async (setBills) => {
  const Ref = collection(db, `bills`);
  const q = query(Ref, orderBy("data.date"));
  const { docs } = await getDocs(q);
  const DataArray = docs.map((item) => (item.data()))
  //setBills(DataArray);
}
```

Comment: i dont know how to continue

Comment: What are you trying to with the reference? If you want to fetch that data then you'll need to query that separately.

Comment: and if I have it as a property of an object. First I have to obtain the data of that object and then consult it separately or how would it be?